# Positive lookahead in Google sheets regex

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have a list of strings as shown in below table. Using regex, I want to extract the string that is before the last comma(,) in each string.

| Book name |
| --- |
| Blue Lock, 1 |
| Naruto, Vol. 9 |
| Harry Potter (novel), Vol 2 |

I have found the regex that does this, `/^.*(?=,\s[vV]ol)/`, but when I use the same in Google sheet, it throws an error that says '"^.*(?=,\s[vV]ol)" is not a valid regular expression'.

What do I need to change to make the regex work on Google sheets?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Sheets regex doesn't support lookarounds.

Try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(.*),")
```

Comment: Works correctly. Ty!

Answer (score 0):

Lookarounds, like `(?<=...)`, `(?<!...)`, `(?=...)` and `(?!...)`, are not supported by the RE2 library.

The best way to convert a regex matching any string up to the first occurrence of a specific pattern in Google sheets, is to use a *capturing group* around the pattern part you want to extract, and use the context pattern part as is, without any lookaround syntax.

E.g. `.*?(?=context_pattern)` can be re-written as `(.*?)context_pattern`.

Mind that `REGEXEXTRACT` only outputs the captured substring(s).

So, you can convert your pattern to

```
^(.*),\s[vV]ol
```